# Messages exchanged between two users SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here][1]I have a schedule of messages between users.

I need a query that returns a list of messages exchanged between specific users by name.

![2]

Now the required result

| UserName | MessageBody |
| --- | --- |
| Mohammad118 | xxxxxxxxxxx |
| BaraaHo | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| Mohammad118 | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |

Current query attempt:

```
select Users.UserName, Messages.MessageBody
from Users, Messages
where Users.UserId = Messages.MessageSender
   or Users.UserId = Messages.MessageRecipient
   and Users.UserId in (select Messages.MessageSender 
                        from Users, Messages
                        where Users.UserId = Messages.MessageSender
                          and Users.UserName = 'Mohammad118')
   and Users.UserId in (select Messages.MessageRecipient 
                        from Users, Messages
                        where Users.UserId = Messages.MessageRecipient
                          and Users.UserName = 'BaraaHo')
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (not as images...)

Comment: So  - what have **YOU** tried so far? Where are you stuck?? How can we help?

Comment: Your query uses 2 different tables, Users and Messages, but you have only given us sample data for one table. Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You probably should JOIN users table twice. For sender, and for receiver.)

Comment: How do I send you a picture of the other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply filter for message sender and apply JOIN with Users to get the username as given below:

```sql
;WITH cte_ExchangeUsers as
(select UserId FROM 
Users 
WHERE UserName IN ('Mohammad118', 'BaraaHo')
)
SELET u.UserName, m.MessageBody
FROM Messages as m
INNER JOIN Users as u
ON u.UserId = m.MessageSender
WHERE messageSender in -- Sender is one of the two persons
(
select UserId FROM 
cte_ExchangeUsers 
)
and messageReceipient in -- receiver is one of the two persons
(
Select UserId from cte_ExchangeUsers 
)
```

Comment: This query returned all messages sent by the specified users
But I only need messages exchanged between them

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand for your answer
Please include the entire query

Comment: i have provided comments. basically, we are getting the userids of sender, receipent and then applying filter accordingly

Comment: @YasserGhannam What do you mean ty "include the entire query"???  This is the entire query.  If you don't understand this, I suggest you learn some more SQL.  I think it's straight forward.